# Send a notification when timer reaches 1 minute

Tags: ios, notifications

I am creating an app for iPhone and I need notifications (not notifications that tells you to play the game again). I need a notification that tells the user when something you have started is done.

I have made a timer running in the background of my app when closed. I just want to make is when the timer is on 1 min tell the player it's done with a notification.

```
-(IBAction)deathmatchstart:(id)sender{
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;
    UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    }];
    DeathMatchTime = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1      
    target:self selector:@selector(startdeathmatch) userInfo:nil
    repeats:YES];

    DeathMatchLabel.hidden = NO;
    DeathMatchStart.hidden = YES;
}

-(void)startdeathmatch {
    deathmatchcount = deathmatchcount +1;

    DeathMatchLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i", deathmatchcountmin, deathmatchcount];

    if(deathmatchcount == 59){
        deathmatchcountmin = deathmatchcountmin +1;
        deathmatchcount = 0;
    }
    // CHANGE TO 8
    if(deathmatchcountmin == 1) {
        DeathMatchDone.hidden = NO;
        DeathMatchLabel.hidden = YES;
        getReward.hidden = NO;

    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of setting an bstimer you will need to set a local notification with a 1 minute delay. Using an nstumer in the background doesn't work and can be terminated by the os.

Comment: can you write the code for me i have no ide what you are talking about im new to objective c

Comment: I would suggest you start by reading the docs on local notifications found here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/scheduleLocalNotification: